# How do I fix this key signing issue with NeuroScience Debian?

Tags: ppa, debian

super sleep deprived but coherent. Hopefully not being a complete dope and this laptop has caused me some trouble before. I added the keys from Neuroscience Debian just yesterday no sweat on another machine. Not sure if it's the lack of sleep or what but I'm receiving an error I can't mentally process right now. Thanks for all the help.

Following the instructions on this link: http://neuro.debian.net/ and selecting "Ubuntu Xenial (16.04), USA California Server, I receive this from the instruction outputs:

```
" wget -O- http://neuro.debian.net/lists/xenial.us-ca.full | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/neurodebian.sources.list
--2017-08-21 19:00:02--  http://neuro.debian.net/lists/xenial.us-ca.full
Resolving neuro.debian.net (neuro.debian.net)... 129.170.30.193
Connecting to neuro.debian.net (neuro.debian.net)|129.170.30.193|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 262 [text/plain]
Saving to: ‘STDOUT’

-                     0%[                    ]       0  --.-KB/s               deb http://neurodeb.pirsquared.org data main contrib non-free
#deb-src http://neurodeb.pirsquared.org data main contrib non-free
deb http://neurodeb.pirsquared.org xenial main contrib non-free
#deb-src http://neurodeb.pirsquared.org xenial main contrib non-free
-                   100%[===================>]     262  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2017-08-21 19:00:04 (55.8 MB/s) - written to stdout [262/262]
"
```

That's fine and dandy, problem is the key ain't checking out:

```
"sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 0xA5D32F012649A5A9
Executing: /tmp/tmp.ZGsHDOyuEZ/gpg.1.sh --recv-keys
--keyserver
hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net:80
0xA5D32F012649A5A9
gpg: requesting key 2649A5A9 from hkp server pool.sks-keyservers.net
gpgkeys: key A5D32F012649A5A9 can't be retrieved
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
gpg: keyserver communications error: keyserver helper general error
gpg: keyserver communications error: unknown pubkey algorithm
gpg: keyserver receive failed: unknown pubkey algorithm"
```

I tried clearing any existing keys and re-signing, updating and rebooting. Not a weird cache issue and not a lost packet error. Thanks again for any assistance.

Comment: sounds like their key doesn't exist in the keyservers, or you've got something odd going on?  Typically this isn't solvable by end-users, and needs to be handled by the people publishing the specific software.

Comment: Ok thanks Thomas, I wasn't sure what I could possibly be doing wrong... If there's any info I can provide let me know.

Answer (score 0):

you could also just fetch the key from the neurodebian website directly... see http://neuro.debian.net/faq.html  "What means “The following signatures couldn’t be verified...”?"

Comment: Hi Yaroslav, I was away for some time and my network turned into chaos. I will re-check whether this answer is correct. However on another machine off site I was able to install without any issues- perhaps the key has been fixed or perhaps this is a device specific issue. I will update you within the next few days. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: yes, in general fetching the key from public servers should work.  But some times there are hiccups from the overloaded servers etc.  That is why we also provide that key as a simple download (pointed in the FAQ)